# Error in if (theme$lylab) { : argument is of length zero

Tags: r, plot, quantmod

```
library(quantmod)
aapl<-getSymbols("aapl", auto.assign =FALSE)
head(aapl)
chart_Series(aapl, subset='2010::2010-04', 
theme =chartTheme(), 
TA="addvo();addbbands()")
```

I get this error from running this code:

> "Error in if (theme$lylab) { : argument is of length zero"

I thought that is perfectly fine because basic example in textbook 
but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
chart_Series(aapl, subset='2010::2010-04', 
             theme =chart_theme(), 
             TA="add_Vo();add_BBands()")
```

`chartSeries` uses `addVo` and `chartTheme`, but `chart_Series` uses `chart_theme` and `add_Vo`, etc.  Don't try to mix the old plotting system with the new one (which uses `_` in function names).